# Google Play Services with Proguard in Android Studio

Tags: android, eclipse, proguard, android-studio, google-play-services

I've recently move across from Eclipse to Android Studios. I had my app using Proguard via eclipse and now that I've move across I'm getting the following errors.

Error:

```
ProGuard: [myApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil: can't find referenced field 'int auth_client_availability_notification_title' in class com.google.android.gms.R$string
ProGuard: [myApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil: can't find referenced field 'int auth_client_play_services_err_notification_msg' in class com.google.android.gms.R$string
ProGuard: [myApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil: can't find referenced field 'int auth_client_requested_by_msg' in class com.google.android.gms.R$string
ProGuard: [myApp] Warning: com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpLoader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient
ProGuard: [myApp] Warning: com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpLoader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.HttpResponseCache
ProGuard: [myApp]       You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
ProGuard: [myApp] Warning: there were 9 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
ProGuard: [myApp]          You may need to specify additional library jars (using '-libraryjars').
ProGuard: [myApp] Warning: there were 3 unresolved references to program class members.
ProGuard: [myApp]          Your input classes appear to be inconsistent.
ProGuard: [myApp]          You may need to recompile them and try again.
ProGuard: [myApp]          Alternatively, you may have to specify the option 
ProGuard: [myApp]          '-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers'.
ProGuard: [myApp] java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
ProGuard: [myApp]   at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:321)
ProGuard: [myApp]   at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:211)
ProGuard: [myApp]   at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:86)
ProGuard: [myApp]   at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:492)
```

Proguard file:

```
# This is a configuration file for ProGuard.
# http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/usage.html

-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-verbose

# Optimization is turned off by default. Dex does not like code run
# through the ProGuard optimize and preverify steps (and performs some
# of these optimizations on its own).
-dontoptimize
-dontpreverify
-dontshrink

# If you want to enable optimization, you should include the
# following:
# -optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!code/simplification/cast,!field/*,!class/merging/*
# -optimizationpasses 5
# -allowaccessmodification
#
# Note that you cannot just include these flags in your own
# configuration file; if you are including this file, optimization
# will be turned off. You'll need to either edit this file, or
# duplicate the contents of this file and remove the include of this
# file from your project's proguard.config path property.

-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgent
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class * extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment
-keep public class * extends android.app.Fragment
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

# For native methods, see http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#native
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
        native <methods>;
}

-keep public class * extends android.view.View {
        public <init>(android.content.Context);
        public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
        public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
        public void set*(...);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
        public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
        public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
     public void *(android.view.View);
}

# For enumeration classes, see http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#enumerations
-keepclassmembers enum * {
        public static **[] values();
        public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}

-keep class com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng { *; }

-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
        public static <fields>;
}

# The support library contains references to newer platform versions.
# Don't warn about those in case this app is linking against an older
# platform version.    We know about them, and they are safe.
-dontwarn android.support.**

#Needed by google-api-client to keep generic types and @Key annotations accessed via reflection
-keepclassmembers class * {
    @com.google.api.client.util.Key <fields>;
}

-keepattributes Signature,RuntimeVisibleAnnotations,AnnotationDefault,*Annotation*

-dontwarn sun.misc.Unsafe

#ActionBarSherlock
-keep class android.support.v4.app.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v4.app.** { *; }
-keep class com.actionbarsherlock.** { *; }
-keep interface com.actionbarsherlock.** { *; }

-keepattributes *Annotation*

#My android stuff
-keep class javax.annotation.Nullable
-keep class org.apache.http.** { *; }
-dontwarn org.apache.http.**

#PDF stuff
-keep class net.sf.andpdf.crypto.** { *; }
-dontwarn net.sf.andpdf.crypto.**

#Google Analytics
-keep public class com.google.** {*;}

#Otto
-keepclassmembers class ** {
        @com.squareup.otto.Subscribe public *;
        @com.squareup.otto.Produce public *;
}

#Google Play service
-keep class * extends java.util.ListResourceBundle {
        protected Object[][] getContents();
}

#Hockey
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable

-keep public class javax.net.ssl.**
-keepclassmembers public class javax.net.ssl.** {
    *;
}

-keep public class org.apache.http.**
-keepclassmembers public class org.apache.http.** {
    *;
}

-keepclassmembers class net.hockeyapp.android.UpdateFragment { 
    *;
}

#Butter Knife
-dontwarn butterknife.Views$InjectViewProcessor
-keepclassmembers class **$$ViewInjector {*;}
```

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18646899/proguard-cant-find-referenced-class-com-google-android-gms-r

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up putting in the following lines, so that Proguard stopped warning me. The build still runs as expected.

```
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil
-dontwarn com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpLoader
```

Comment: You should really have accepted the other answer and perhaps added a comment about the extra line you added.

Comment: Personally I try to use wildcards for ignoring warnings as little as possible. I agree that the answer by Marco W. is a good answer, and I have up voted it. However the code that I am using is provided in my answer, this is why I have accepted it as the answer to my question.

Answer (score 18):

For the "Picasso" library, you just have to add this to your ProGuard configuration:

```
-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.**
```

This is because "Picasso" has an *optional* library that is called "OkHttp". This is not included, but not needed, either.

For the Google Play Services, there seems to be some inconsistency with the library. You should update your library files and clean the project.

Comment: What is the library used for? Hope it won't cause any ClassNotFoundExceptions

Comment: OkHttp is an alternative HTTP client, which _can_ be used instead of Android's or Java's built-in ones or not. So you definitely don't need it and it won't cause any `ClassNotFoundExceptions`. I'm using Picasso without OkHttp as well. More about OkHttp: http://corner.squareup.com/2013/05/announcing-okhttp.html