# Deploying signed apk from android studio to device

Tags: java, android, gradle, dependencies, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to deploy **signed** apk from android studio. I have configured the build.gradle with required credentials but I've got some warnings when I try to build the .apk. I tried adding some commands in **proguard** rules but still I get same warnings. How can I fix this issue?

Here are the pictures of the issue.

[image]
[image]

And this is the gradles file.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'android-apt'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
//apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
android {
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias 'something'
            keyPassword 'something'
            storeFile file('D:/something')
            storePassword 'something'
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.aam.skillschool"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-youtube:v3-rev179-1.22.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
    compile 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.3.1'
    compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.5'
    apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0'
    debugCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.5'
    releaseCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.5'
    apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.7'
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.7'
    provided 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    compile 'br.com.mauker.materialsearchview:materialsearchview:1.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-android:+'
    compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:+'
    compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-gson:+'
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using "GoogleAuthUtil" any where ?It's deprecated now.. Also use  `useLibrary  'org.apache.http.legacy'` for getting rid off http issue.

Comment: I am not using GoogleAuthUtil anywhere. where do i add this?

Comment: below  buildToolsVersion "25.0.0" will be ok

Comment: nope it doesn't help i get the same error even now

Comment: Hm .. seems like a proguard issue then .May be you can do something like this .http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16931847/google-play-services-with-proguard-in-android-studio or this http://stackoverflow.com/a/24109609/3111083

Answer (score 1):

you have the non-use classes of your imported libraries already deleted by proguard, revert back to the version where u had no pro-guard applied,that version should work.Then carefully include all your exceptions and rules of all your libraries in your pro-guard rules and then try to use the proguard

Comment: I have emptied the pro-guard and sync the project. I get no error except some warning of ```Warning:WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.0.1 is ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.``` and ```Warning:WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.0.1 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.``` but when i run the project i get the same errors as above

Comment: yes ,because gradle thinks the libraries you included actually exist in ur build. but when you build,it look for specific classes and as proguard has stripped those away they can no longer be found.So i think you should try the suggestion i made .I encountered the same issue as you and solved it this way

Comment: ```Then carefully include all your exceptions and rules of all your libraries in your pro-guard rules and then try to use the proguard```  how can i do that? please guide here

Comment: visit the pages of all the libraries you are using ,generally every library developers includes instructions to added to proguard for their library

Comment: to me its strange that i can manually remove signingConfigs from build.gradle and set ```minifyEnable  false``` and then i generate signed apk then android studio generate the signed one without any error. just a warning related to httpclient

Comment: if you are able to generate the release apk,where and when do u get the errror then ?

Comment: I get error when i want to generate release apk using run button from android studio

Comment: Yes i am generating signed apk like this build->generate signed apk.

Comment: basically i want to debug the signed apk since i am using in app billing. So i want to add some functionalities that depends on the response from in app billing.

Comment: and like u mentioned ,minifyEnable false, will disable the function/checks that proguard runs.So its evident it will throw error if used.I m not particullarly sure abt this,but i guess proguard is the one that actually runs the classes checks

Comment: if debug is the target u hold, then u can simply run all your builds with minify set to false.Nd turn to true only when u release to store,would that work for u ?

Comment: nd have u tried reverting back to the last known working build ?

Comment: I'd check on this will let you know about it then. Thanks for your attentions to this question

Comment: Yes i did. which was the ``` build->generate signed apk```

Comment: if u find a more robust solution , please leave a link for that .ty